# How to get access token in Nodejs using @okta/okta-auth-js signInWithCredentials method

Tags: node.js, okta

I am new to Okta authentication in nodejs, I've been struggling to get an access token. I am using okta-auth-js's signInWithCredentials.

```
new OktaAuth({
      issuer: OKTA_AUTHORISER_ISSUER_URI,
      clientId: OKTA_WEB_APP_CLIENT_ID,
      redirectUri: OKTA_REDIRECT_URI,
      responseType: "token",
    });
```

```
await this.authClient.signInWithCredentials({
      username: email,
      password,
    });
```

But this only gets me a sessionToken. How can I get an access token after this? I think I am missing setting an authState here but I am not sure how to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like that to get back the access token :

```
await this.authClient.signInWithCredentials({
  username: email,
  password,
});
this.authClient.isAuthenticated().then(value => {
  if (!value) {
    console.log('not authenticated');
  } else {
    authClient.tokenManager.get('accessToken').then(value => {
      console.log(value.accessToken);
    })
  }
})
```